# Time difference between two timestamps - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

Just getting into Oracle for the first time. how to find the time difference between the below in Oracle.

```
to_char(CAST(b.start_time AS DATE),'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss') as start_time    
to_char(CAST(b.end_time AS DATE),'dd-MON-yy hh24:mi:ss')  as end_time
```

I need to get the time difference in hours and minutes for end and start times, means (end_time - start_time).

Appreciate your help.

Comment: what are the data types of your start_time and end_time columns?

Comment: @Boniest, Thanks for your response, actually the below works but i want to get in hours and minutes. **(CAST(( b.end_time ) AS DATE )  - CAST((b.start_time ) AS DATE ))  * 24 * 60 AS Layove** , (This resulting only in minutes)

Comment: BTW, TIMESTAMP(6) is datatype of both

Answer (score 1):

Find the day, hour and minute components of the difference using `EXTRACT` and then concatenate them into a single string:

```sql
SELECT (EXTRACT(DAY FROM end_time - start_time)*24
       + EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time - start_time))
       || ':'
       || TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM end_time - start_time), 'FM00')
         AS difference
FROM   table_name
```

*Note: If you only parse the hours and minutes then you will not know if the difference is greater than 24 hours.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (start_time TIMESTAMP(6), end_time TIMESTAMP(6) );

INSERT INTO table_name (start_time, end_time)
SELECT TRUNC(SYSTIMESTAMP), SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2022-01-03 00:00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DIFFERENCE |
> | --- |
> | 14:15 |
> | 48:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8a43ed515db9b4bec1254db8a501600d)*

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
b.end_time - b.start_time
```

Result is an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` value, see [INTERVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00200)

In order to get hours and minutes you can use either `SUBSTR` / `REGEX_SUBSTR` / `REGEXP_REPLACE` or [EXTRACT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639)

```
REGEXP_REPLACE((b.end_time - b.start_time), '.*(\d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2}.*', '\1')

EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (b.end_time - b.start_time))||':'||EXTRACT(minute FROM (b.end_time - b.start_time))
```

Comment: This will not get the correct hours and minutes difference if the times are more than 24 hours apart.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract time in Oracle. Make sure your data type is in Datetime format and multiply it with 24 to get hours and 24*60 for minutes.

```
   (b.end_time - b.start_time) * 24    --For Hours
   (b.end_time - b.start_time) * 24*60 --For Minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taking 1970 year and then adding this with the difference between `start_date_time` and `end_date_time` with the require format -> `hh24:mi:ss`

You can try this query:

```
SELECT
   TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') + (TO_DATE('2022-01-18 21:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') - TO_DATE
            ('2022-01-18 19:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')), 'hh24:mi:ss') AS human_readable_format
FROM
   DUAL;
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This does not work if the time difference is greater than 24 hours.

Comment: Ok, I hope you got the solution.